# Updating SQL database duplicated fields based on INT column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `VARCHAR` column in my MySQL database called `firstname` and an `INT` column called `allcount`. I would like find all of the duplicated rows based on the `firstname`'s value and change two other columns based on the `allcount` columns value.

This is how it looks like now:

```
id   |  firstname    |  allcount | address   |  email
1    |   John Doe    |    3234    | some data |  johndoe@randomfakeemailxy.com  
2    |   John Doe    |     31    | some data |  johndoe@randomfakeemailxy.com
```

And I would like to achieve this:

```
id   |  firstname    |  allcount | address   |  email
1    |   John Doe    |    3234   | some data |  johndoe@randomfakeemailxy.com  
2    |   John Doe    |      31   | empty     |  empty
```

So I wouldn't like to delete the duplicates, I just want to set the address and email fields where the `allcount` value is less.

Based on other questions I could find the duplicates withn this SQL command:

```
select firstname, count(firstname) as myCount 
from mytable 
group by firstname having myCount > 1 
order by myCount;
```

And I can also update fields with this code:

```
UPDATE mytable SET 
  address = "empty" , email = "empty";
```

However I can't chain the two snippet and update the fields based on the allcount value (only update where the `allcount` value is less). How can I achieve this?

Comment: I believe `address = "empty" AND email = "empty"` should be `address = "empty", email = "empty"`, or it may evaluate to a very different thing.

Comment: @9000 I think I was wrong. I changed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change all but the *first* row for each name.  In MySQL, use `join`:

```
update mytable t join
       (select firstname, min(id) as min_id
        from mytable 
        group by firstname
        having count(*) > 1 
       ) tt
       on t.firstname = tt.firstname and t.id > t.min_id
    set address = 'empty',
        email = 'empty';
```

Note the use of `,` in the `set` clause.  `and` is acceptable -- and does nothing that you would ever want (it treats the expression as a boolean expression).

Comment: Gordon, I don't understand it exactly. Can you please tell me that do I need to use anything from the snippets in my question? `myCount` and 'allcount' is not the same. 'allcount' is a column in my database, and I assume 'myCount' is a variable (in the snippet I use to find the duplicates). I would like to edit the duplicated fields where the value of `allcount` is less.

Comment: @rihe . . . My bad.  That should be `count(*)`.  The `having` condition is not even necessary.  I left it in to fix it, but you can just as easily let the `on` condition do the filtering.